# How would I achieve a unique result using the Linq method syntax

Tags: c#, linq, unique

I have the following data in a table:

e.g. data

```
0, 'Ford'    
1, 'Toyota, Toyota'  
2, 'BMW'  
3, 'Porsche, Porsche'  
4, 'BMW'
```

I need to place this data in the following type `List<Tuple<int, string>> carList` so that the results within my list would appear as follows:

```
0, 'Ford'    
1, 'Toyota'  
2, 'BMW'  
3, 'Porsche'  
4, 'BMW'
```

using the following pseudo code:

```
while (SQLiteDataReader.Read())  
{  
    carList.Add  
    (  
        new Tuple<int, string> (   
                                 SQLiteDataReader.GetInt32(0) ,   
                                 SQLiteDataReader.GetString(1).[Some extension method to produce unique items]
                               );
    )  
}
```

Note, when there are items with duplication (Toyota, Porsche) , the duplication will always be the same name. i.e you won't get something like 'Toyota, Ford'.

Is there some extension method that would remove the duplication part?

Comment: You might also check out the Tuple.Create factory method.  Might clean up what you have a bit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
SQLiteDataReader.GetString(1).Split(',').First().Trim()
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking to do the whole thing through a linq query, this should work.

If you're just looking to fix your pseudocode, then scottm's solution should work.

```
LinqDataContext db = new LinqDataContext();
List<Tuple<int, string>> results = 
   db.Cars.AsEnumerable()
          .Select(c => Tuple.Create(c.id, c.Make.Split(',')[0].Trim()))
          .ToList();
```

Comment: I don't think this does what the OP wants. In your example, c.Make is still going to be 'Toyota, Toyota' not just 'Toyota'

Comment: @scottm, yeah, I think you're right.  I fixed the solution so at least it's right, but it's clear you figured out what he meant before I did.  +1